# ejs website got a variable from server side, and not working propertly

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I use Node.js, express and ejs

Client got a variable from server side

```
res.render('Messagess.ejs', {friendsdatas:friends, myaccount:accresult, mytoken:cookies.LoginToken})
```

I use this variable in html code like this. This working properly.

```
<% for (var i=0; i<friendsdatas.length; i++) { %>
  <p class="name"><%= friendsdatas[i].Username %></p>
<% } %>
```

But inside the script section, I can't use like how I want

```
for (var i = 1; i<'<%=friendsdatas.length %>'; i++) {
  console.log('<%=friendsdatas[i].id %>')
}
```

Here I got error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwVAP.png)

If I use the variable like this, that working properly

```
console.log('<%=friendsdatas[1].id %>')
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case,

```
<% for (var i=0; i<friendsdatas.length; i++) { %>
  <p class="name"><%= friendsdatas[i].Username %></p>
<% } %>
```

code that is inside <% %> is executed by server. Since the control structure (for) is inside <% %>, it can run and read `friendsdatas`.

However, the other case

```
for (var i = 1; i<'<%=friendsdatas.length %>'; i++) {
  console.log('<%=friendsdatas[i].id %>')
}
```

This for part is run by the client side. The client side can't access `friendsdata.id` so it can't be run.

```
<% for (var i = 1; i<'<%=friendsdatas.length %>'; i++) { %>
  console.log('<%=friendsdatas[i].id %>')
<% } %>
```

This will output i console.log statement. Or alternatively

```
<% 
let friendsdatasString = JSON.stringify(friendsdatas);
%>
<script>
let friendsdatas = <%- friendsdatasString %>;
for (var i = 1; i<friendsdatas.length; i++) {
  console.log(friendsdatas[i].id)
}
</script>
```

Pass the server side variable to client side variable and loop normally for client side.